# How to make a ScrollViewer work without specifying a static height or width?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm currently working on UI for a WPF application, and I want to use a ScrollViewer to show the content that might be out of the viewing area of the screen.

I've read all over the internet in the past 2 days, and from what I understand: the ScrollViewer doesn't have knowledge of it's content's/parent's height unless determined statically; thus if there's no specific height written down (in a case of a StackPanel underneath it for example) it won't allow for scrolling.

Now, let's suppose my UI hierarchy looks like this:

```xml
<Window> <!--No height here-->
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        <ContentControl>
            <UserControl> <!--This user control doesn't have a specific height or width-->
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <Grid /> <!--This grid doesn't contain any StackPanels, or containers with dynamic height, and this is content I want to show-->
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid />
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I expected the ScrollViewer to scroll appropriately since there's no dynamic container beneath it, but it didn't, and it appeared that setting a static height to it or to the UserControl above it made it work.

But since the app would work on different screen sizes, and all windows are somehow resize-able, I don't want to write static dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use fractional sizes for the grid (which gives scrollviewer height somehow), example:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--this gives the second row the space it needs and leaves the scrollviewer with all the remaining space, this will also work if you need to make the second row child fixed-->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0"/>
  <Grid Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

for a better experience with grids, use WpfAutoGrid.